# numbers printed on credit card

Tags: privacy

My question is about the credit card it's self, Is there a law that requires me to have my card numbers printed on card, can I have a card that on front of card
 have my full name, 
kind of card , {visa, master card, amex,discover}
the issuing Bank name
 then on back 
have the good thru date
ccv security #
and all other info that is listed

if the card information that is needed to use the card is stored on the strip on the back , that is gathered when card is swiped for my protection can I have my credit card issued to me with no number so someone cant copy the info off card and use it .

Comment: Just FYI, you don't need your full name on the card. You can have FirstInitial Lastname, just like in the ads. One bank even told me I could get an imprint in any name as long as it wasn't to be used fraudulently.

Answer (score 1):

The format of the card is established by the card brands and followed by the issuing banks. Banks will follow the established card production standards since most outsource their card production.

There are third party products, like [this one](https://newatlas.com/card-20-hidden-and-multiple-account-credit-cards/16401/), which do exactly like you mentioned. These products also allow you to store multiple cards on the same device. These products don't support EMV chips so their lifetime is limited as chip continues to replace mag stripe.

Finally, consider what security you are looking by hiding the card number. You are protecting yourself from someone capturing the number by seeing your card. Most credit card fraud happens via either skimmers or by capturing large numbers of cards numbers via electronic methods. Before modifying your card I would start with using chip whenever possible, being very selective of the ATMs you use, and limit the number of places where you have your credit card number stored.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting question. I’m not aware of any rules specifying that a card number needs to be on a card, the type of transaction you’re referencing is called a ‘card present’ transaction. When a card is physically present and swiped/inserted into a machine to read off the numbers.

There is a separate class of transaction called ‘card not present’ , and those typically refer to online transactions when a customer keys in their credit card details into an app/browser for online shopping.

Since most customers don’t have card readers at home, the bank typically prints these on the card to enable customers to read their card details while shopping online.

There is however a CVV2 number, typically a 3-digit number printed on the back of the card. The CVV2 is never stored electronically on the mag stripe or even the chip, it is just printed on the card and meant to facilitate ‘card not present’ transactions. This number is what merchants typically request for online transactions.

If you’re worried about someone reading your card number and then using it to shop online, you can actually just scratch the CVV2 number off. That way, it’s worthless for an online transaction.

‘Card Present’ is much harder to carry out, but not impossible. However to answer your question, I doubt (very much) that any bank will issue you a card with no embossed number on it, no harm trying though.